# ERROR: dependency ‘RcppArmadillo’ is not available for package

Tags: rcpp, rcpparmadillo

I am trying to build my own Rcpp package, it works pretty well in my local computer, now I am installing it into another computer, the following error pops up:

**ERROR: dependency ‘RcppArmadillo’ is not available for package "my_package_name"**

Below is some information about the environment (by sessionInfo()):

> R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
>
> Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
>
> Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
>
> Matrix products: default
>
> BLAS:   /usr/lib/openblas-base/libblas.so.3
>
> LAPACK: /usr/lib/libopenblasp-r0.2.18.so
>
> locale:   [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C   [3]
> LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8   [5]
> LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   [7]
> LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C   [9] LC_ADDRESS=C
> LC_TELEPHONE=C
>
> [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
>
> attached base packages:
>
> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
>
> [1] compiler_3.6.3

In the DESCRIPTION file, I already have

`Linking to: Rcpp, RcppArmadillo`

One action I tried but still did not work is installing the development versions of BLAS and LAPACK as suggested in https://support.bioconductor.org/p/117905/

Is there anyone knows which causes this error? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  First things first: does "the other computer" have RcppArmadillo installed?

Comment: Oh, I know what is happening.  You are running a three year old R version there.  That R version no longer has a matching RcppArmadillo at CRAN.  So _either_ do (outside of R) `sudo apt install r-cran-rcppamradillo` for a quick binary installation from Ubuntu, or fetch one of the older RcppArmadillo releases of the archive link at CRAN and install it by hand.  Or, higher end solution, learn how to (easily) get (current) R onto (older) Ubuntu.  16.04 is seriously outdated though so that is the root of your issues.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Hey Dirk, thanks so much for the detailed answer and your contribution for the community. It works when I install the RcppArmadillo by ```Rscript -e 'install.packages("RcppArmadillo")'```